# Using reg expression to resolve a url rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am unable to get my specific url rewrite to work.

Could you help me with the following 301

http://example.com/component/user/?task=register#content

to

http://example.com/home/register

Thanks - I have never been able to get far with reg exps.

Answer (score 0):

The hash portion of a URL is not able to be seen by the server.  The best you can do is:

```
Redirect 301 /component/user/?task=register /home/register
```

Comment: That won't work and is the reason why (those chars need escaping apparently) it needs to be done using a regular expression to escape those characters, I'm just not getting it to work with what I think

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task=register#content$
RewriteRule ^/component/user/$ http://site.com/home/register [L,R=301]